# Export to Excel while maintaining starting zero using Gridview and LINQ

Tags: c#, excel, linq, gridview, model-view-controller

I seem to be losing the starting zero when I export my model to excel. Some values in my database have values of ex.'0345' or '0001'. When I export them to excel, the excel sheet is showing '345' or '1'. How do I maintain the leading zeros? My application is using MVC 5, and I'm populating the the `gv.DataSource` using the LINQ statement `db.lookup_client_name.ToList();` I've read other articles which states to set the values as a string with a  `'` (single quote) at the start OR adding a `\t` before your string. How do I accomplish this via a LINQ statement? My code is below...

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string Value)
    {
            var gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = db.lookup_client_name.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=LookupClientName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") + ".xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();


        return RedirectToAction("/");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a "cheap trick" to create an excel, you aren't creating an excel, you are creating a HTML page and Excel tries to do it's best to convert that to an excel sheet.

Said that, as Excel sees those values as a numeric values they're converted to numbers and that's why the leading zeroes are removed.

Basically it's not possible to define the cell format using the HTML trick, so if you really need to preserve those zeros you must or create a real XML file and specify the data type or add some character before or after those values to avoid Excel to detect it as a number.

If you want to add the char to the value I can't write the exact code because I don't have the `lookup_client_name` content structure, but here is an example which will give you the general idea:

```
//this class represents the structure of the data of the lookup_client_name content
public class RowContent
{
    public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
    public string PreserveValues{ get; set; }
}

//...

gv.DataSource = db.lookup_client_name.
                Select(i => new 
                { 

                    SomeProperty = i.SomeProperty, 
                    PreserveValues = "'" + i.PreserveValues + "'" 

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Gusman, I appreciate the quick response and your feedback. I did some searching online and I found that export method. It sounds like that is not the best approach from your comment. Do you recommend I use a utility via the Nuget Package Manager or a different approach?

Comment: If you want real excel files there are many libraries, I will not recommend any as each has it's flaws. But if you want to continue with the HTML trick read the update to the answer.

Comment: Gusman, that did the trick! Thank you very much for your answer. Thank you!!